# Monitor USB device bandwidth usage

Tags: bandwidth, usb-3, video-capture

I bought a HDMI capture card that is plugged in with USB 3.0. (Elgato HD60S) I would like to know how much data is put through that USB connection. For example when transferring data to external hard drives you can see exactly how high the transfer rate is. Is there any way for me to monitor how much bandwidth is used by that live video feed? The reason I'm asking is that when I connect that capture card to a PCIe USB 3.0 four port HUB, I don't get a picture, just a dark screen. However if I plug it into the computer's USB 3.0 ports "directly" I get a clear feed. I would like to figure out why that is, I'm suspecting through the PCIe USB 3.0 four port HUB not enough data can be transmitted to allow for a live-feed of the video, resulting in a black screen. Another reason could be that the device "knows" it is plugged into a hub and not directly and refuses its service, because the manufacturer specifically said on their website their hardware must be plugged in "directly".

Comment: Your theory about the HUB isn't practical.  The port you are connecting to, is considered to be a USB HUB also, it's just internal to your device (i.e. a single USB IC).  Your theory on the bandwidth might be a plausible explanation.  However, PCIe 3.0 should be more than enough, for the limited transfer capabilities of USB 3.2 Gen 1

Comment: I see. So then the question really is why I get a black screen when using the device via that expansion card.

Comment: It makes it even more difficult to troubleshoot as I don't get any error log or message, just nothing besides a black screen in the Elgate software's Live-view (and in OBS Studio as well)